# 2 language site ability

Tags: support, languages, russian-stackoverflow

I am a native English speaker, but have learned Russian (and Spanish) well enough to converse in-person, read, do basic writing, and read Stack Overflow na russkom. When I am logged into my account in English, is there some quick way I can click a link or tab to switch to Stack Overflow na russkom and search among questions and posts there?

My accounts seem to be linked, but I wish there were a quicker, easier way to switch between the two.

Comment: Browser tabs? Do you have the two sites in "your communities" (right-most icon in the black top bar)?

Comment: Oh yes, I have "Current Communities", and then "Your Communities", and it is there. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Catija already mentioned in the comment you always have a quick way to change the current community via top bar popup:

> [image: top-bar]

More over if your browser "accept-language" option contains a Russian language you will see a special text block on some questions on Stack Overflow in English. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array):

> [image: on ruSO too]

Clicking the link in that block will redirect you to the [same question](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626264/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) on Stack Overflow in Russian.